# Copying list item to another list based on department selected in list

Tags: list-workflow

I'm attempting to set up a workflow that can copy a list item to another list based on the department selected. So there would be 5 different potential web parts the list item could be copied to. How do I go about this? I thought I could set up a copy item command in the workflow but how do I accomplish looking at the various departments and moving to the corresponding web part?

Thanks for the help!